# Run Angular Cli Ng Serve over https 2018

Tags: angular, https

Is there a way I can run my angular localhost over https?? I have tried a few different tutorials but nothing has worked Ive tried.. [serve your angular cli app over https](https://freerangeeggs.net/2018/03/14/serving-your-angular-cli-app-locally-over-https/) but it would still serve over http:// has anyone succesfully done this? If so can you point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: @PardeepJain There must be a way to run a development angular app over https

Comment: Your best option would be to run a server with a certificate. You can check [let's encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) for that, and how to create a server. Then, you should be able to access your application over https.

Answer (score 1):

Another option, if you don't have a certificate and want to use a self-signed for testing purposes, just to add the flag `"start": "ng serve --ssl",` to the package.json, it will generate one when serving the app.

```
Angular CLI: 7.3.1
Node: 8.11.3
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 7.2.5
```

Command:

```
npm start
```

Output:

```
> ng serve --ssl
** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, 
open your browser on https://localhost:4200/ 
     10% building 4/4 modules 0 activei ｢wds｣: Generating SSL Certificate
```